# Parameterized Type declaration

Tags: c#, generics

Inside webApi method i declare list of specific type:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetWhType([FromUri] RequestParams myParams)
{
     List<WhType> myResult;
     ...
     return this.Ok(myResult, 0);
}
```

How can I declare myResult type based on parameter value, like:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetWhType([FromUri] RequestParams myParams)
{
     if(myParams.type===1)
         List<WhType> myResult;
     else
         List<ChannelType> myResult;
     ...
     return this.Ok(myResult, 0);
}
```

Probably using generics?

Comment: Well, other than using == instead of === (you're such a frontend developer), this should work as you've hypothesized.  Did you try it?  Did it not work?  If so, please [edit] to add details as to why it didn't work.  I'd suggest, however, that you not mix return types in a single controller method, based on a url parameter.  I think it would be more clear to have separate methods returning a predictable type, design wise.

Comment: And it's also better to use `switch` statement then `if-else`s

Comment: Thank you. I didn't try since I thought there is some other alternative.
This is only part of code which is different, so, I thought to have it in one method. WhType class has 6 properties for example. What do you suggest when I need to return whType with 3 properties and other time with all properties? Create new whType1 class(with 3 properties) or is it possible to say return whType with only 3 properties? The point is that I don't won't to return on client all columns in json if client doesn't need them. I would like to optimize things.